# Can I trigger a Fault Sequence using a custom Java mediator?

Tags: wso2-esb

I've created a Custom mediator in Java that generates a token. If this generation fails the mediate() method returns false. I want to trigger a specific Fault Sequence I have defined in the configuration.

This custom mediator is inside a sequence and the onError of this sequence is set to the fault sequence I want to run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that the Custom Java class is extending the AbstractMediator class.

There is a function `handleException()` from the AbstractMediator class that I can use to specify the error and this triggers the fault sequence that I have specified in the Sequence configuration.